# Unsafe character in password rest api false

Tags: laravel, rest, api, ionic-framework, unsafe

How to handling unsafe character ( " < > # % { } | \ ^ ~ [ ] `") in my password using rest api laravel. example : <<@Dmin91.
my authenticate attempt always get false in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regular expression to allow special characters

^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\x])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$

E.g.

```
'password' => 'required| min:6|
           regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|
           confirmed',
```

Comment: is that for validation? validation return true, but when go to the next step in auth:: attempt always get false